# Set title attribute with LabelFor from viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a setup in my frontend, where I use the title tag from a label, to show a helper icon with text.

I would like to show a value from my viewmodel, in the title tag of the label (like `<label title="TitleText">DisplayNameText</label>`).

I have the following Razor:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.FinancingPayout, new { Class = "infoicon" })
```

This is my viewmodel:

```
[DisplayName("- Udbetaling:")]
public string FinancingPayout { get; set; }
```

How do I get to add an attribute on the viewmodel, so it shows in the title tag of the label?

Comment: Replacing `new { class = "infoicon" }` with `new { class = "infoicon", title = "The Title" }` should do the trick. If you want to solve this generically it'll be more work..

Comment: @manuFS that would not read the value from the viewmodel

Comment: Do you want to use an attribute on you property - something like `[Title("TitleText")]public string FinancingPayout { get; set; }`?

Comment: You need to create a class (say `TitleAttribute`) that inherits from `Attribute` and implements `IMetadataAware` to add a value to the `ModelMetadata`, then you need to create you own implementation `@Html.LabelFor()` to extract the value and render the html `title` attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this tutorial, it is basically doing what you want to do, just Setting a tooltip instead of title Attribute:

http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/14/creating-your-own-modelmetadataprovider-to-handle-custom-attributes/

As I said in the comment earlier, for a generic solution you will need to do some work, but fortunately you can copy/paste most of the code from the tutorial.

Update: if what Stephen Muecke said is true (and I assume it is), then you can skip the custom Metadataprovider if you add the Interface `IMetadataAware` to your custom attribute. It will be added to the `AdditionalValues` automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.FinancingPayout, new { @class = "infoicon", title = "TitleText" })
```

### Edit 1

You need to create a method (most probably a static method) like this

`LocalizationLogic.cs`

```
public static String GetLocalizedString(String keyName)
{
    // you can apply database or from xml file logic here to get the Translated string
    switch (keyName)
    {
      case "TitleText":
        return "Localized Title Text";
        break;
    }
    return String.Empty;
}
```

Then use this method inside your view

```
@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.FinancingPayout, new { @class = "infoicon",
    title = LocalizationLogic.GetLocalizedString("TitleText") })
```

Comment: It is a nice solution, but it does not read the title value from the viewmodel. I would like to remove all internationalization logic from the view